Defining the slope of a vector bundle
Given a Kähler manifold $X$ and a holomorphic vector bundle $E$, then the slope of $E$ is defined by
$$
\mu(E)=\frac{\int_X c_1(E)\wedge [\omega]^{n-1}}{\text{rk}(E)}.
$$
I tried to find some motivation for this definition, but could not find much anything. If someone here knows a reference where this is discussed or knows why this is defined the way it is, I would appreciate that.

It comes from characterization of stable bundles (Narasimhan-Seshadri) and moduli space of stable bundles in terms of GIT

It is a very long story which one should probably start with Mumford's Geometric Invariant Theory dealing with algebraic group actions on algebraic varieties $X$ and the Hilbert-Mumford numerical criterion for stability of points $x\in X$. This theory provides a natural framework for forming various moduli spaces. One of these, is the moduli space of vector bundles over algebraic varieties. It turns out that the Hilbert-Mumford stability condition in this setting is provided by a "slope inequality." You can read a detailed discussion (with references) in  section 8 of chapter 9 in
Mumford, D.; Fogarty, J.; Kirwan, F., "Geometric invariant theory."
Ergeb. Math. Grenzgeb. (2), 34[Results in Mathematics and Related Areas (2)] Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 1994, xiv+292 pp.
For a more analytic (or differential-geometric) perspective, see
"Differential geometry of complex vector bundles."
Kobayashi, S. Princet. Leg. Libr.
Princeton University Press, Princeton, NJ, 2014, xi + 304 pp.
One more thing, namely, why is it called "slope": One way to interpret Hilbert-Mumford stability condition for a point $x\in X$ is that there is a 1-parameter subgroup $H$ of $G$ acting on $X$ and one has a strictly convex function on the  $H$-orbit through $x$. The stability criterion amounts to asking for this convex function to have a unique minimum. For a convex function $f(t)$ of one real variable this is equivalent to strict positivity of the "asymptotic slopes" of $f$:
$$
\lim_{t\to\pm \infty} f'(t). 
$$
In the case of holomorphic vector bundles this condition turns out to be equivalent to an inequality in terms of the slope $\mu(E)$ (the bundle $E$ plays the role of a point $x\in X$).
